# How could the derivative's graph be derived given this antiderivative's graph?

Tags: integration, limits

In this particular question, how is it possible to derive the shape of the derivative graph, $h(x)$, from its antiderivative, $H(x)$, for $0\le x \le 1$? I can see why $h(1)=0$, as $H(1)$ looks like a minimum, but cannot see why the shape of $h(x)$ for $0\le x \le 1$ is the way it is. How do you know that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+} h(x)$ is $-2$, for example?

The portions of the functions in black are given by the question, and the blue portions are the solutions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $0 \lt x \lt 1$, you can see that $H(x)$ is decreasing, so $h(x) < 0$. As you've pointed out, it looks like $H(x)$ flattens out towards $x \rightarrow 1^-$, so $h(x) \rightarrow 0$.

It's not perfectly clear, but if you mirrored the bit of $H(x)$ from $-1 \lt x \lt 0$ over to $0 \lt x \lt 1$, it looks like that would serve as a tangent to the actual $H(x)$ near $0$, so that suggests that $h(x) \rightarrow -2$ as $x \rightarrow 0^+$.

Of final note, there don't appear to be any inflection points or major shifts in gradient for $H(x)$ in $0 \lt x \lt 1$, so anything where $h(x)$ smoothly joins $(0, -2)$ to $(1, 0)$ should be fair game. Personally I would have guessed that a straight line would work, but maybe there's some clue I've missed.

Comment: I had the same thought process regarding the shape of $h(x)$ between $0 \le x \le 1$, but couldn't exactly see why its shape is the way it is.

Comment: The main other thing I guess you could look for is to see where a tangent of slope -1 would go, and it does look like it's somewhere between $0.5 \lt x \lt 1$, rather than exactly on $x = 0.5$ as the straight line derivative would suggest.